# R installed.packages() randomly stopped working on windows 7

Tags: r, package

`installed.packages()` command in R lists your installed packages.  Mine was working for almost a year and then this command randomly started throwing an error.  As this is a built-in command, I am not even sure how to "reinstall" it or address this.  Any ideas how to fix the error and get the command working again?

```
> installed.packages()
Error in gzfile(file, mode) : cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning message:
In gzfile(file, mode) :
  cannot open compressed file `'C:\Users\Mitch\AppData\Local\Temp\Rtmp6Dawpa/libloc_190_4464fd2b.rds', probable reason 'No such file or directory'`
```

One suggestion on here involved this in combination:

- `.libPaths()`
- `installed.packages(lib.loc = 'my path')`

The results of this produced yet another error as shown here.  Looks like an issue with the installed file still but how to address is the question:

```
> installed.packages(lib.loc = 'C:/ProgramFilesCoders/R/R-3.3.2/library')
Error in gzfile(file, mode) : cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning message:
In gzfile(file, mode) :
  cannot open compressed file 'C:\Users\Mitch\AppData\Local\Temp\Rtmp6Dawpa/libloc_190_4464fd2b.rds', probable reason 'No such file or directory'
>
```

Comment: If you `debug(installed.packages)` and run it, and step through the code, you'll likely find "something wrong" with the call to [`.readPkgDesc(lib, fields)`](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/R-3-3-branch/src/library/utils/R/packages.R#L604) (link edited for the R-3.3 version, since changed in R-3.4), since that appears to be the only function call that could find errant info.

Comment: sometimes the simplest answer is the best.  I feel stupid for not realizing this.  My RStudio environment has been up for a while because I had a lot of threads open of things I was working on.  I tried closing RStudio, letting it save the env. to .RData, and re-opening and it trying it again.  The command then worked.  Cassic windows.  When in doubt, reboot. But all of the research on here will be useful should this recur and a simple "close and re-start" approach does not solve it. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes the most simple obvious solution is what works:

- I closed my RStudio environment saving it to .RData
- I re-opened RStudio and tried the command again
- it worked

For the future, some good ideas got posted on here before I thought to try the above.  Here are the suggestions that others included in case the above does not work if this problem is encountered by anyone in the future:

1. Use `.libPaths()` to find out proper path where this is installed, and then re-run the command with the path included in it like so: `installed.packages(lib.loc = 'your path')`
2. Try debugging it with: `debug(installed.packages)`; Expectation is that we will likely find something wrong with `.readPkgDesc(lib, fields)` while stepping through debug.  This was not tried yet so you may encounter things not written up here when you do try it.
3. Try Updating R in case it is out of date with these commands: `library(installr)` and `updateR()`.

Answer (score 1):

That is odd.

What version of R are you running, standard R or Microsoft R? And did you recently update?

If you did recently update, perhaps your packages did not get copied over, hence the 'No such file or directory' statement.

If you haven't updated, I would install a newer version and see if it fixes the issue.

If your uncertain, you can always use the `updateR` function to check if you have the latest version and choose to install it or not.

```
library(installr)
updateR()
```

Good luck,

Comment: `version` command yields additional info and this string: `R version 3.3.2 (2016-10-31)`.  There were some updates to windows, but no recent updates I am aware of to my R environment specifically (I think).  I do have a lot of packages I installed months ago for classes I was taking (back when `installed.packages()` worked.  A little concerned about whether an update might break something in my environment or not.

Comment: Keeping your ideas for the future.  Something simple cleared it.  About to post the answer so this content is here for when the problem recurs for me or someone else months from now and I then forget how easy it was to solve.  :-)

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue lies in terms of the where the function is looking for the package information. `installed.packages()` needs an argument `lib.loc`.

From official documentation

```
lib.loc     character vector describing the location of R library trees to search through
```

Looks like the function for some reason is looking in `AppData\Local\Temp` which is the download location and not the installed location.

Without looking at your `R_Home` and `.libPaths()` is difficult to nail down where the problem is, however running `.libPaths()` should give you one or more paths as shown in the below example. None of these should be `temp` locations.

```
>.libPaths()
[1] "C:/Users/UserName/Documents/R/win-library/3.4"
[2] "C:/Program Files/R/R-3.4.0/library"
```

If not, you can set the path  within the `.libPaths("your path")` or pass the path of the library as part of `installed.packages(lib.loc = 'your path')` and try again.

Comment: This looks useful but there is a piece of the puzzle missing.  Are you saying that I use `.libPaths()` to find out paths to try and then use these paths in `install.packages(lib.loc = 'your path') when I try again?

Comment: scratch that question.  Just tried it and got new errors.  Updating the post to include them as part of the issue.  Figuring out the fix on this may be tricky.  second answer of updating R sounds promising but a little concerned about whether that will break anything else.

Comment: If you look at the source for [`installed.packages`](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/43c7014750e076b5c356bd4ae031ab2e7ef9dfa1/src/library/utils/R/packages.R#L619-L684), you'll see that it generates its own `rds` file within the `tempdir()`. I don't think this is a `.libPaths()` or `lib.loc` issue.